# angular.js димамически создать маршрут с помощю ng-repeat и ui-router json файла

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-repeat, ui-router

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите создать динамический маршрут, никак не получается у меня. При клике "view details" должна открываться файл phone-detail.html с "id" того телефона, на который был клик. Есть json файлы, которые находятся в папке phones.Там находится *phones.json*, который содержит список телефонов

`{
        "age": 0, 
        "id": "motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi", 
        "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg", 
        "name": "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi", 
        "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation\r\n\r\nExperience the future with Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb).",
        "status": true
    },`

Eсть страницы index.html, и в папке template (home.html, about.html, contact.html, phone-detail.html).

index.html содержит

```html
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">Phonecat</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ui-sref-active="selected"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav-collapse -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <div class="container">

    <ui-view></ui-view>

  </div>
```

A home.html содержит

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 item" ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:search">
         <div class="preview-img text-center">
          <img ng-src="{{ phone.imageUrl }}" alt="{{ phone.name }}">
          <span class="label"
           ng-init="status = phone.status ? 'Есть в наличии' : 'Под заказ' "
           ng-class="{'label-success':phone.status,'label-warning': !phone.status}">
           {{ status }}
          </span>
         </div>
          <h2>{{ phone.name }}</h2>
          <p>{{ phone.snippet }}</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="phones/{{ phone.id }}" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          
        </div><
```

phone-detail.html содержиттекст, выделенный жирным шрифтом

```html
<!-- phone-detail.html -->
<h1>Phone Information {{ phoneId}}</h1>
```

В controller.js все нормально работает, кроме ссылки которая находится в home.html, не как не могу сделать так чтоб клик на ссылку открывал detail-phone.html с id того телефона на который был клик

```js
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ui.router']){
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'template/home.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl',
    })

    
    .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'template/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl',
      })
    
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'template/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    })
    .state('phones',{
     url: '/phones/{phoneId}',
     templateUrl: 'template/phone-detail.html',
     controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
     }
    })
        

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';

 }]);



//About Controller
phonecatApp.controller('AboutCtrl',['$scope', '$http','$location', function($scope,$http,$location){

}]);
//Contact Controller
phonecatApp.controller('ContactCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope,$http,$location){

}]);

//phone detail controller
 phonecatApp.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$stateParams' , function($scope, $http, $location,$stateParams){
 $scope.phoneId=$stateParams.phoneId;

 }]);

//PhoneList Controller
 phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location', function($scope, $http,$location){  

$http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data, status, headers ,config) {
      $scope.phones = data;
  });

 }]);
```

Помогите настроить PhoneDetailCtrl и state('phones',.....) чтоб норм работали ссылки . state('phones',.....) не работает

Comment: Что пишет в консоли при клике и есть ли какие-то ошибки при загрузке страницы? Вы уверены, что по данному пути `$http.get('phones/phones.json')` у вас находит файл с данными, может всё-таки стоит указать абсолютный путь?

Comment: Выдает ошибку angular.js:12261 GET http://localhost:8000/template/phone-detail.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: да файл находится в phones/phones.json , вед оттуда же отображаются телефоны и картинки и дескриптион,которые видите  на картинке сайта который тоже выложил

Answer (score 0):

Все нашел ошибку. Надо было написать в state('phones',....)

```
.state('phone',{
    url: '/phone/{phoneId}',
    templateUrl: 'template/phones-detail.html',
    controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl',
})
```

а в home.html поправить

```
<p><a class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="phone({phoneId: phone.id})" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
```

вот так

Comment: а в home.html sss

Comment: может всё таки `ng-href`, а не `ui-sref`?

Comment: с помощю ngroute делал до ui-route , но на форумах прочитал вроде самый лучший это ui-route, поэтому и сменила на него.